# Is there a generator that will turn a stream of text into a stream of lines?

Tags: python, network-programming, generator, python-2.4

I am working with a network library that returns a generator where you receive an arbitrary amount of text (as a string) with each Next() call; where if you simply concatenated the result of every Next() call; would look like a standard English text document.

There could be multiple newlines in the string returned from each Next() call, there could be none.  The returned string doesn't necessarily end in a newline, i.e. one line of text could be spread across multiple Next() calls.

I am trying to use this data in a 2nd library that needs Next() to return one line of text.  It is absolutely critical I do not read in the entire stream; this can be tens of gigabytes of data.

Is there a built-in library to solve this problem?  If not, can someone suggest the best way to either write the generator or an alternative way to solve the problem?

Comment: without knowing anything about the structure of the incoming text, this is fairly difficult to answer. Please add more to your question

Comment: Does the structure of the text really matter?  It's a bunch of textual data with newlines in it.  The generator is returning strings.

Comment: Can you build your own using `for line in stream.split('\n'): yield line`?

Comment: @Bill I'm not very familiar with python.  If you're talking about the stream classes in io; those are in Python 2.6+; this is Python 2.4.  The object I'm working with doesn't appear to have a split() method either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a generator function that pulls the chunks down and splits them into lines for you. Since you won't know if the last line ended in a newline or not, save it and attach it to the next chunk.

```
def split_by_lines(text_generator):
    last_line = ""
    try:
        while True:
             chunk = "".join(last_line, next(text_generator))
             chunk_by_line = chunk.split('\n')
             last_line = chunk_by_line.pop()
             for line in chunk_by_line:
                 yield line
    except StopIteration: # the other end of the pipe is empty
        yield last_line
        raise StopIteration
```

Comment: In Python 2.4, this requires some slight changes since that overload of .join and next(...) didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your edit, maybe you could modify the stream object which returns arbitrary amounts of text? For example, in the `stream.next()` method, there is some way the stream generates a string and `yields` it when `.next()` is called. Could you do something like:

```
def next(self):
    if '\n' in self.remaining:
        terms = self.remaining.split('\n')
        to_yield, self.remaining = terms[0], ''.join(terms[1:])
        yield to_yield
    else:
        to_yield = self.remaining + self.generate_arbitrary_string()
        while '\n' not in to_yield:
            to_yield += self.generate_arbitrary_string()
        to_yield, self.remaining = terms[0], ''.join(terms[1:])
        yield to_yield
```

This pseudocode assumes that the stream object generates some arbitrary string with `generate_arbitrary_string()`. On your first call of `next()`, the `self.remaining` string should be empty, so you go to the `else` statement. There, you concatenate arbitrary strings until you find a `newline` character, split the concatenated string at the first `newline` character, yield the first half and store the second half in `remaining`.

On subsequent calls of `next()`, you first check if `self.remaining` contains any `newline` characters. If so, yield the first line and store the rest. If not, append a new arbitrary string to `self.remaining` and continue like above.